# NEWID function causing error for prepared statement in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I am trying to create a forgot password system, so I am using the `NEWID()` function to create a random code to be sent to the user's email. I am using prepared statements to prevent SQL injections, but this still isn't working:

```
$sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO verifyEmail (username, code) VALUES (?, NEWID())");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "s", $user);
mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
```

I am getting a warning on line two that the first parameter can't be a boolean. (Thus, there is a syntax error in the SQL code). I know that the `NEWID()` function is the issue, since removing it fixes the warning. Does `NEWID()` not work inside prepared statements? If so, how should I go about doing this? Also, I am required to then run a `SELECT` statement to get what value the `NEWID()` function returned. Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: This is the first time I've heard if the newid() function

Comment: Relevant [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NEWID()` is a SQL Server function, that does not exist in MySQL. The equivalent would be [`UUID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid):

```
$sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO verifyEmail (username, code) VALUES (?, UUID())");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "s", $user);
mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
```

As explained in the documentation, `UUID()` gives you a *utf8 string of five hexadecimal numbers in aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee*.